# after recording audio file , where this file will be saved?

Tags: cordova

I have used the following code to record MP3:

```
function recordAudio() { var src = "myrecording.mp3"; var mediaRec =
    new Media(src,  function() {           
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");    
    },
    //error callback
    function(err) {   
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
    });
    //Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();
}
```

My question is where will the MP3 file "myrecording.mp3"  be saved? Will it be saved inside my application? And how can I get full path of that mp3 file?

Comment: Beware that mp3 encoding is not currently supported on Android : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

in ios: `cordova.file.tempDirectory` 
in android: `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory`

After recording, you should move the file created to the folder that you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the device that your application is deployed to.
In an **iOS** application it will be saved

```
/var/mobile/Applications/<Random generated ID like: 5E3A873A-9E80-443E-91BA-E2F962929359>/Documents/recording.wav
```

In an **Android** application it will be saved to

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/recording.mp3
```

I'm not completely sure if these paths are correct now, but you can get a handle on the files and check yourself quite easily.

```
function createFile(path){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
            path, { create: true, exclusive: false }, getFileWin, getFileFail
        );
    }, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
}

// getFile Success & Fail Methods
function getFileWin(fileEntry){
    console.log("File created at " + fileEntry.fullPath);
}

function getFileFail(error){
    console.log("Failed to retrieve file");
}

// requestFileSystem Fail Method
function getFSFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```